# Is there any known application for normal numbers?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

**Background:** I am writing a master thesis on the complexity of the expansions of algebraic numbers in some complex basis $\beta$ with $|\beta| > 1$. This is a very small step towards proving the

> *Conjecture.* Every irrational algebraic number is absolutely normal.

Here a real number $\alpha$ is said to be *normal* in base $b$ or $b$-*normal* (where $b > 1$ is an integer) if every sequence of $n$ consecutive digits (for every positive integer $n$) appears in the $b$-ary expansion of $\alpha$ with the same frequency.
Further, a number is said to be *absolutely normal* if it is normal in every integer base $b > 1$.

**Question:** This led me to wonder if there is any known application for normal numbers, i.e. some (proved or conjectured) statement of the form

> *If* $\alpha$ is normal, *then* [something interesting in terms of $\alpha$] happens.

I'm asking here because, while I could find a wealth of information regarding normal numbers *per se*, I couldn't find any uses for them. The only [interesting result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Connection_to_finite-state_machines) I was able to find is that normal sequences cannot be compressed by a lossless finite-state compressor. In other words (if I interpret this correctly), there is no way to encode the $b$-ary expansion of a normal number with a shorter sequence of finitely many less symbols (without losing information).

Comment: Isn't the question of whether $\sqrt2$ normal unknown? (Or you think you're about to solve it?)

Comment: "Finite-state compressor" is a quite strong assumption on the compressor. If you relax the finite-state requirement, every _computable_ normal number (such as the Champernowne constant) can be "compressed" to the program that computes it.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Of course not! That's why I said that it is a *very small step*. :) I extended a proof of Adamczewski and Bugeaud where they showed that the complexity function (i.e. the number of different blocks of a given length) of the $b$-ary expansion of an irrational algebraic number grows more than linearly. Note that the $b$-ary expansion of every $b$-normal number has exponential growth (though the converse isn't true).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for the remark. Sadly, it makes that result slightly less interesting, making this question even more relevant for me.